# Trying to balance my dataset through sample_weight in scikit-learn

Tags: class, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm using RandomForest for classification, and I got an unbalanced dataset, as: 5830-no, 1006-yes. I try to balance my dataset with class_weight and sample_weight, but I can`t.

My code is:

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(arrX,y,test_size=0.25)
cw='auto'
clf=RandomForestClassifier(class_weight=cw) 
param_grid = { 'n_estimators': [10,50,100,200,300],'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']}
sw = np.array([1 if i == 0 else 8 for i in y_train])
CV_clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, param_grid=param_grid, cv= 10,fit_params={'sample_weight': sw})
```

But I don't get any improvement on my ratios TPR, FPR, ROC when using class_weight and sample_weight.

Why? Am I doing anything wrong?

Nevertheless, if I use the function called balanced_subsample, my ratios obtain a great improvement:

```
def balanced_subsample(x,y,subsample_size):

    class_xs = []
    min_elems = None

    for yi in np.unique(y):
        elems = x[(y == yi)]
        class_xs.append((yi, elems))
        if min_elems == None or elems.shape[0] < min_elems:
            min_elems = elems.shape[0]

    use_elems = min_elems
    if subsample_size < 1:
        use_elems = int(min_elems*subsample_size)

    xs = []
    ys = []

    for ci,this_xs in class_xs:
        if len(this_xs) > use_elems:
            np.random.shuffle(this_xs)

        x_ = this_xs[:use_elems]
        y_ = np.empty(use_elems)
        y_.fill(ci)

        xs.append(x_)
        ys.append(y_)

    xs = np.concatenate(xs)
    ys = np.concatenate(ys)

    return xs,ys
```

My new code is:

```
X_train_subsampled,y_train_subsampled=balanced_subsample(arrX,y,0.5)
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X_train_subsampled,y_train_subsampled,test_size=0.25)
cw='auto'
clf=RandomForestClassifier(class_weight=cw) 
param_grid = { 'n_estimators': [10,50,100,200,300],'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']}
sw = np.array([1 if i == 0 else 8 for i in y_train])
CV_clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, param_grid=param_grid, cv= 10,fit_params={'sample_weight': sw})
```

Comment: I cant reproduce that on a toy dataset (I mean I get better precision/recall with the first snippet). Could you post your results on TP, FP rates, etc? For instance the output of `print(classification_report(y_test, CV_clf.predict(X_test)`. I'm puzzled by your "new code" because you are **still using `class_weight` and `sample_weight`** on top of your custom balancing.

Comment: My bad, I was not using imbalanced classes. Still the auc result with the first snippet is better for me than with the second one, so it would be nice if you could post your metrics.

Comment: CASE 1: With class_weight='auto' and sample_weight='1-8' (as you can see i the code), I obtain TPR=0.17 and FPR=0.004. CASE 2: But when I use the function balanced_subsample with subsample_size=0.5 (as you can see i the code), I obtain TPR=0.85 and FPR=0.13. In this second case, I realised that trying again with the same value, the ratios change a lot, but always much better than CASE 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer yet, but hopefully it'll help get there.

First some general remarks:

- To debug this kind of issue it is often useful to have a deterministic behavior. You can pass the `random_state` attribute to `RandomForestClassifier` and various scikit-learn objects that have inherent randomness to get the same result on every run. You'll also need:

  ```
  import numpy as np
  np.random.seed()
  import random
  random.seed()
  ```

for your `balanced_subsample` function to behave the same way on every run.

- Don't grid search on `n_estimators`: more trees is always better in a random forest.
- Note that `sample_weight` and `class_weight` have a similar objective: actual sample weights will be **`sample_weight` * weights inferred from `class_weight`**.

Could you try:

- Using subsample=1 in your `balanced_subsample` function. Unless there's a particular reason not to do so we're better off comparing the results on similar number of samples.
- Using your subsampling strategy with `class_weight` and `sample_weight` both set to None.

**EDIT**: Reading your comment again I realize your results are not so surprising!
**You get a better (higher) TPR but a *worse* (higher) FPR**.
It just means your classifier tries hard to get the samples from class 1 right, and thus makes more false positives (while also getting more of those right of course!).
You will see this trend continue if you keep increasing the class/sample weights in the same direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comments. I will try your approaches to get a more "stable" an accurate classifier.

Answer (score 1):

There is a imbalanced-learn API that helps with oversampling/undersampling data that might be useful in this situation. You can pass your training set into one of the methods and it will output the oversampled data for you. See simple example below

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler

ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=1)

x_oversampled, y_oversampled = ros.fit_sample(orig_x_data, orig_y_data)
```

Here it the link to the API: http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/api.html

Hope this helps!